# interpret an integer as enum flags

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

Suppose I have a Flag enum like this:

```
From enum import Flag
class suspicion(Flag):
     TOT_PCNT_LOW = 1
     IND_PCNT_LOW = 2
     IND_SCORE_LOW = 4
```

And suppose I have an integer that was constructed using these flags

```
i = suspicion.IND_PCNT_LOW.value | suspicion.TOT_PCNT_LOW.value      # i == 3
```

How do I get a list of the names of the flags that are set in the integer? For example:

```
print(some_method(i))   # prints ["IND_PCNT_LOW", "TOT_PCNT_LOW"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup code:

```
from enum import Flag
class Suspicion(Flag):
     TOT_PCNT_LOW = 1
     IND_PCNT_LOW = 2
     IND_SCORE_LOW = 4

a_flag = Suspicion.TOT_PCNT_LOW | Suspicion.IND_PCNT_LOW
```

In Python before 3.10

```
def flag_names(flag):
    return [f.name for f in flag.__class__ if f & flag == f]
```

---

It's slightly easier in 3.10+

```
def flag_names(flag):
    # Python 3.10+
    return [f.name for f in flag]
```

---

In either case:

```
print(flag_names(a_flag))
```

gets you

```
['TOT_PCNT_LOW', 'IND_PCNT_LOW']
```

---

If the incoming `flag` argument may be an integer instead of a `Suspicion` member, you can handle that as well:

```
def flag_names(flag, enum=None):
    """
    returns names of component flags making up flag
    if `flag` is an integer, `enum` must be enumeration to match against
    """
    if enum is None and not isinstance(flag, Flag):
        raise ValueError('`enum` must be specifed if `flag` is an `int`')
    enum = enum or flag.__class__
    return [f.name for f in enum if f & flag == f]
```

Comment: Thanks, Ethan, this answered my question but I was not as clear as I should have been.  I have checked this answer and will re-enter my question more precisely.

Comment: @WesR:  I updated my answer to handle that use-case.