# Interpret an integer as Python enum flags

Tags: python-3.x, enums

I asked this question in [interpret an integer as enum flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66361220/interpret-an-integer-as-enum-flags/66361396#66361396) but did not state the challenge as clearly as I should have. I am looking for how to take a pure integer, not an instance of a class based on Flags, and interpret the integer according to the definitions in the class.

Suppose I have a Flag enum like this:

```
From enum import Flag
class suspicion(Flag):
     TOT_PCNT_LOW = 1
     IND_PCNT_LOW = 2
     IND_SCORE_LOW = 4
```

And suppose I have an integer that has bits set consistent with the definition, but is just an integer. It is ot an instance of the suspicion enumeration.

```
i == 3
```

How do I get a list of the names of the flags that correspond to the bits in the integer?

For example:

```
print(some_method(i))   # prints ["IND_PCNT_LOW", "TOT_PCNT_LOW"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the possible flags & evaluate if the corresponding bit is set. Use the enum value for the check. And then you can access the `.name` attribute of the enum object to get the name associated with the value

Like so:

```
from enum import Flag


class suspicion(Flag):
     TOT_PCNT_LOW = 1  # 001
     IND_PCNT_LOW = 2  # 010
     IND_SCORE_LOW = 4 # 100


i = 3 # 011


def flags_set(num):
    return [sus.name for sus in suspicion if num & sus.value]

print(flags_set(i))
```

Prints:

```
['TOT_PCNT_LOW', 'IND_PCNT_LOW']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can instantiate a new `suspicion` object with the value `i`. python will join corresponding names with a `|` symbol:

```py
>>> i = 3

>>> suspicion(i)
<suspicion.TOT_PCNT_LOW|IND_PCNT_LOW: 3>

>>> suspicion(i).name
'TOT_PCNT_LOW|IND_PCNT_LOW'

>>> suspicion(i).name.split('|')
['TOT_PCNT_LOW', 'IND_PCNT_LOW']
```